# Why date '+%s%N' not working on mac terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, date, terminal

I am working on bash scripts on both linux and mac.

I run this command on remote server with linux OS and it just work perfect.

```
CURRENT_TIME=$(date '+%s%N') 
echo "$CURRENT_TIME"
```

However, when I run the same command on mac terminal, it shows this error:

```
1654778186N: value too great for base (error token is "1654778186N")
```

It look like mac terminal did not recognized the '%N'. What should I do to fix the issue on mac terminal?

Comment: Are you sure you're running bash on Mac, rather than zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%N` is a GNU extension to the POSIX standard, as clarified in GNU's own documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Time-conversion-specifiers.html

The POSIX version of `date`, doesn't include `%N`: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html

If I recall correctly, POSIX-certified systems (and macOS is certified) cannot add custom extensions to POSIX tools to guarantee portability across systems.

Comment: As to what you could do to 'fix' it, some suggest using homebrew to install GNU coreutils and use GNU's date, but I am not familiar enough with macOS to tell how good this workaround is and how it will fit your purpose.

Comment: Yes, I did install the GNU coreutils and it works. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there would be an issue with *adding* a conversion specification like `%N`, as long as you don't change the meaning of one of specifications provided by POSIX. There is a *lot* of extra functionality in both the BSD and GNU versions of `date` that aren't defined by POSIX.

Comment: (BSD `date`, for example, allows `%F` as a shortcut for `%Y-%m-%d`, which POSIX does not require or mention.)

Comment: Compare with the POSIX definition of `echo`, which not only doesn't mention something like `-n` to suppress a newline (like `bash`'s built-in supports), but explicitly *forbids* any options for `echo`. (Even `/bin/echo` on macOS fails to adhere to the POSIX specification.) Even the POSIX specification seems to throw its hands into the error with regards to enforcing `echo`'s adherence to the specification,and simply suggests using `printf` when portability is desired.

Comment: `POSIX-certified systems (and macOS is certified) cannot add custom extensions to POSIX tools to guarantee portability across systems` this is absolutely wrong. For example [there are Linux distros that's UNIX certified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476945/44425), and Linux typically use GNU userspace with GNU extensions

Comment: UNIX certification is not the same thing as POSIX compliance, though. As far as I know, there is no POSIX certification process. One can be POSIX compliant without actually being officially certified as a (proper) UNIX. (For Apple, I suspect it was worth the time and money  to "prove" that Mac OS X, as it was known at the time, really was Unix, not just something they claimed to be like Unix.)

Comment: POSIX certification exists and it's not the same thing as whatever a UNIX certification is: http://get.posixcertified.ieee.org/certification_guide.html

Comment: And on whatever extensions GNU and BSD have already added, I don't know what point that makes unless BSD is certified, which I think is not, but I can't tell for sure. GNU is definitely not certified.